# primefaces and jqplot plugin

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

What is the different (if there is) between primefaces chart and 
http://www.jqplot.com/index.php ?

Its look like the examples in the jqlot website has much more functionality options

Thanks

Comment: Primefaces uses jqplot under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed out PrimeFaces uses jqPlot to render the charts. Regarding the functionality options I can't fully agree. You can always use the `extender` option of PrimeFaces charts. By writing an extender function you gain access to the jqPlot configuration object before the actual rendering happens.

Examples:

- [Example using PF 3.4 chart extender function?](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22851)
- [Displaying decimal places on primefaces pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083796/displaying-decimal-places-on-primefaces-pie-chart).