# How to customize a PrimeFaces bar chart property using jQuery or jqPlot

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jqplot, bar-chart

I am using [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/) 3.2. If I am using the below [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) file and want to customize the barChart legend position to the outside grid and modification in tooltip with customized message, how I can write the code where my data series values is still retrieved from View1.chartModel bean?

I am looking for actual code and steps...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p ="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" library="css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh"
              content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=timeout.xhtml" />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
                      onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>
        <p:dialog modal="false"
                  widgetVar="statusDialog"
                  header="Status"
                  draggable="false"
                  closable="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
        </p:dialog>

        <h:form id="ViewRep"
                style="padding:10px;">
            <p:growl id="messages"
                     showDetail="true"/>
            <p:growl id="growl"
                     showDetail="true"/>

            <div style="position:absolute;left:310px;top:620;width:920;height:360px;">

            <p:panel  id="pnl1"
                      header"Trend"
                      style="width:920;height:360px;"
                      toggleable="true"
                      closable="true"
                      toggleSpeed="500"
                      closeSpeed="500"
                      widgetVar="panel1">
                <p:barChart id="BarChart1"
                            value="#{View1.chartModel}"
                            widgetVar="bar1"
                            legendPosition="n"
                            barPadding="5"
                            barMargin="10"
                            style="width:98%;height:300px;" />
                </p:panel>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since PrimeFaces doesn't expose those options, you would need to use an `extender function`.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096427/primefaces-and-jqplot-plugin

Comment: thank you, is this extender funtion supported in primefaces 3.2 ???

Comment: I believe extender is not available in primefaces 3.2, I have used 3.4 version and it is running now..

Comment: The XHTML is not well formed -  see near *header"Trend"*.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to update your PrimeFaces version and then you should use extender, but if you don't want to update, you can run JavaScript code on your page load. Use **plot** to make changes on your chart.

An example for legend location:

- First you should set your **widgetVar="barChart"** on your chart component:

  ```
  <p:barChart id="basic" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" widgetVar="barChart"
              title="Basic Bar Chart" min="0" max="200" style="height:300px"/>
  ```
- Then write this JavaScript code on your page load.

  function redrawChart() {
          barChart.plot.legend.location="se";
          barChart.plot.redraw();
      }

Or call **redrawChart()** when you need it.

Good Luck!